# How to remove all and add some new elements with config transforms

Tags: .net, xml, xslt, app-config

I have the following block in my web config

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="dev" />
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="file" />
        <logger name="*" minLevel="Info" writeTo="growl" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

I would like it to transform it by removing all rules and adding a new one

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="graylog" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

I've tried this

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <rules>
        <logger xdt:Transform="RemoveAll" />
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="graylog" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

but that merely clears out the `<rules>` element.

Whats the correct transform?

Comment: Don't you need to specify `xdt:Transform="Insert"` on the new element?

Comment: @lc. Indeed! Would be swell if their documentation mentioned that, huh? Want to put that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Tell me about it. I've included a link to the documentation too, in the hopes this helps fill in the gaps for the next person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also specify a [transform action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the new record:

```
<logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="graylog" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
```